Active choice plugin, dynamic change of parameter fails
Currently, I am using the Active Choices plugin to configure my pipeline.
I have 3 different parameters that are used to build the pipeline.
The 2nd parameter, updates on the value selected for the 1st parameter.
The 3rd parameter, updates on the value selected for the 2nd parameter.
However, what I observe is that the value of the 3rd parameter remains the same for that particular build number ( irrespective of any different option selected in 2nd parameter).
The 3rd parameter value(in the current build) is the value of the results from the click of 2nd parameter(in the previous build)
For eg:
In the second parameter, I select branch2. IFF i had selected branch2 in my previous build for 2nd parameter, it would show me the values: model3,model4. IFF NOT, then some other values all together.
In the image, inspite of clicking on branch1, it still shows the values in parameter3 from the previous run

My code:
properties([     
    parameters([  
        [$class: 'CascadeChoiceParameter',             
        choiceType: 'PT_SINGLE_SELECT',             
        name: 'RUN_TESTS',
        script: [                 
            $class: 'GroovyScript', 
            fallbackScript: [
                classpath: [], 
                sandbox: true, 
                script: 'return ["ERROR"]'
            ],                
        
        script: [       
            classpath: [], 
            sandbox: true,             
            script:""" 
                return ["YES","NO"]    
            """        
            ]             
        ]],        
        [$class: 'CascadeChoiceParameter',             

        choiceType: 'PT_RADIO' ,       
        name: 'BRANCH',       
        referencedParameters: 'RUN_TESTS',                  
        script: [                 
            $class: 'GroovyScript', 
            fallbackScript: [
                        classpath: [], 
                        sandbox: true, 
                        script: 'return ["ERROR"]'
            ],                
               
        script: [       
            classpath: [], 
            sandbox: true,             
            script:""" 
                if(RUN_TESTS.equals("YES")){
                    return ["${getDummyBranches().join('","')}"]
                }else{
                    return ["Disabled: Select 'Yes' to enable"]
                }    
            """    
            ]
        ]] ,
        [$class: 'CascadeChoiceParameter',             
        choiceType: 'PT_CHECKBOX',     
        //choiceType: 'PT_RADIO' ,       
        name: 'MODEL_INFO',     
        description: 'Select the test model to build?',  
        referencedParameters: 'BRANCH',                 
        script: [                 
            $class: 'GroovyScript', 
            fallbackScript: [
                        classpath: [], 
                        sandbox: true, 
                        script: 'return ["ERROR"]'
                ],                
                
        script: [       
            classpath: [], 
            sandbox: true,             
            script:""" 
                if(BRANCH!=null && !BRANCH.isEmpty() && !BRANCH.contains("Disabled:")){
                    return ["${getDummyModels(BRANCH).join('","')}"]
                }else{
                    return ["Disabled: Select the appropriate branch above"]
                }    
            """  ]
        ]]                            
  
    ]) 
])  

def getDummyBranches() {      
    return ["branch1", "branch2", "branch3"]
} 

def getDummyModels(valu) {     
    if (valu.equals("branch1")) {    
        println("inside the branch1 condition")           
        return ["model1", "model2"]     
    } else if (valu.equals("branch2")) { 
        println("inside the branch2 condition")       
        return ["model3", "model4"]    
    } else {         
        return ["model5", "model6"]     
    } 
}

node {
    stage('Print Parameters') {
            println "xxx"
    }
}




JenkinsVersion: 2.447
ActiveChoices: 2.8.3
How to achieve the dynamic behavior on the 3rd parameter immediately?
Suggestions/ideas are most appreciated

Your getDummyBranches() and getDummyModels(valu) methods are called during job execution and they help setup parameters in the job definition. These parameters will be used during the next execution and you can see them if you click on the Configure menu. User interaction with the parameters happens before a job is executed, actually before it is even retrieved from the scm, so the methods you defined are not available at that stage. Groovy scripts for the active choice parameters have to be self contained, they cannot call methods in your pipeline or in your shared libraries.
